# Change corresponding div content based from selection in an array of dropdowns

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, html, onchange

I have an array of dropdowns (), each has its corresponding div. Both are dynamically created with PHP. What I want to do is to change the content of a dropdown's corresponding div based from the value of the selected dropdown.

I tried this code and it worked for a single pair of dropdown and div.

HTML

```
<select id="selectField" style="padding-left: 20px;width:150px">
        <option value="option1">Cat</option>
        <option value="option2">Dog</option> 
<option value="option3">Lion</option> 
    </select>
 <div id="option1" class="block">Felis catus</div>
 <div id="option2" class="block">Canis lupus familiaris</div>
 <div id="option3" class="block">Panthera leo</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectField').change(function () {
        $('.block').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
});

});//]]>  

</script>
```

But it didn't work for an HTML like this with 2 sets of select and div elements.

```
<select id="selectField[]" style="padding-left: 20px;width:150px">
        <option value="option1">Cat</option>
        <option value="option2">Dog</option> 
<option value="option3">Lion</option> 
    </select>
 <div id="option1" class="block">Felis catus</div>
 <div id="option2" class="block">Canis lupus familiaris</div>
 <div id="option3" class="block">Panthera leo</div>

<select id="selectField[]" style="padding-left: 20px;width:150px">
        <option value="option1">Cat</option>
        <option value="option2">Dog</option> 
<option value="option3">Lion</option> 
    </select>
 <div id="option1" class="block">Felis catus</div>
 <div id="option2" class="block">Canis lupus familiaris</div>
 <div id="option3" class="block">Panthera leo</div>
```

Any suggestions how to get this working? I have no idea how to manipulate array of elements in jQuery. Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: I just have to clear this. There are **n** number of dropdowns and **n** number of corresponding divs. **n** is determined by the user. I created an array of dropdowns so I could easily fetch the selected values using PHP. Thus, naming each dropdown uniquely makes it impossible for me to get all the selected values using PHP.

In the event that the value of the **i**th dropdown is changed, I would also like to change the content of the **i**th div corresponding the changed dropdown. How would I do this?

Comment: id='selectField[]' is not a proper way for declaring id's to controls and you cant assign two same id's to control try unique id's or assign same class to both...

Answer (score 0):

try following instead:

```
<select id="selectField1" style="padding-left: 20px;width:150px">
        <option value="option1">Cat</option>
        <option value="option2">Dog</option> 
<option value="option3">Lion</option> 
    </select>     
<select id="selectField2" style="padding-left: 20px;width:150px">
        <option value="option1">Cat</option>
        <option value="option2">Dog</option> 
<option value="option3">Lion</option> 
    </select>
 <div id="option1" class="block">Felis catus</div>
 <div id="option2" class="block">Canis lupus familiaris</div>
 <div id="option3" class="block">Panthera leo</div>

$('.block').hide();
$('#selectField1,#selectField2').change(function () {
    $('.block').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zApq4/10/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that doesn't solve the problem. Please see my question again. I made some edits.

Comment: @galibee: just show me the both arrays snippet i will make fiddle as you want.